# Interact Slider missing in plot

Tags: julia, gadfly

While using both Interact and Gadfly packages in Julia, the sliders which are supposed to appear (coming from Interact) in the plots don't show up. Here's an example of code:

```
using Gadfly
using Interact
set_default_plot_size(15cm, 15cm)

f(x)= e^x
x =-10:0.001:10

@manipulate for a in 1:5, b in 4:9

plot(
    layer(x=x, y=f.(x)*a, Geom.line),
    layer(x=[-10; 10], y=[10000; 10000], Geom.line),
    Coord.Cartesian(xmin=0,xmax=10)
)

end
```

I am running Julia on version 0.6.2.

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. My run shows sliders just fine. Are you sure you are running your code in a IJulia/Jupyter notebook? Also are your Jupyter version is greater than 3.0? `Interact` requires a notebook (Jupyter > v3.0) to function. 

Also you need to `Reactive` for real-time interaction (i.e. `using Interact, Reactive`)

Comment: I had a similar issue with separate jupyter and IJulia installations. I uninstalled jupyter and let IJulia install its own jupyter version, and the problem disappeared. See IJulia docs and search the list of closed issues.

Comment: @Hckr Yes I am sure on both of your questions. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @MigueldeDeus Is there any warning/error or something? Could it be related to your web browser? Can you try it with a different browser?